# determine if the first row of a db list is done - java

Tags: java, list

I have a list that pulls from the database. The list can contain multiple rows from the entity as illustrated

```
book
id | name
1  | foo
2  | zee

users
id | type | bookfk
1  | E    | 1
2  | E    | 1
```

Now am fetching a list of books from users with a corresponding id of 1.
Below is my attempt

```
List <Users> userList = userService.findByBookId(bookId);
//the looping
    for(Users usr : userList) {
    .....having trouble here to know if the loop is on the second row 
    }
```

The above list works fine but my challenge is to know when the first row has finished looping and it has jumped to the second row.

Comment: Where is the loop here?

Comment: show the code you are having trouble with

Comment: I have shown the looping, from the looping above the list is iterated through in a stretch and I cannot determine the rows from the table

Comment: what do you mean exactly? you can identify row by using user id right?

Comment: I only know of bookId passed in argument I dont know userid

Comment: so you want to perform some operation if it is second record or third record, something like this?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a variable to indicate if this is the first row.
This can either be done using a boolean value of by using a traditional for loop (not a for-each loop)

Boolean variable

```
boolean firstRow = true;
for(Users usr : userList) {
  if (firstRow) {...}
  firstRow = false; 
}
```

For loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size (); i++) {

    if (i == 0) {// first row...}
    // or
    if (i > 0) {// not first row...}

     Users user = userList.get(i); // get the element
}
```

Comment: with the for loop how do I get a field from users eg the user type

Comment: Your logic is sound